# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> error in scapy on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, scapy

I have installed python 2.7.3 and scapy on my ubuntu 12.04 through software center.But now i'm not able to access scapy through python.

like in the terminal first type python (works fine) and then scapy it shows an error written below.

All the simple ip commands work fine in scapy but the send,sr,etc don't work .it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
```

for all the commands i try .
so,pls help me out here .i'm really in the need.

Comment: Could you show as the code that is causing this? It is hard to guess from your description!

Comment: i'm not able to use send,sr command.i'll show the code i'm using:

Comment: ok,i'll show the code in terminal after scapy i'm using:send(IP(dst="192.168.254.137")/ICMP()).it shows the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):File "<console>", line 1, in <module>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 251, ........ 307, in __init__self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(type))file"/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init___sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: Please, put that into your question... Nobody likes to read code in comments!

Answer (score 1):

From your comment - `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

When running a Python script that uses Scapy, or just running Scapy from terminal, if you want to send packets over the wire, you need to call it with root or administrative rights.

So using the terminal -

```
# Works, but won't be able to send or receive packets.
rypeck@laptop:~$ scapy
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> 

# Will work!
rypeck@laptop:~$ sudo scapy
Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0)
>>>
```

Scripts you call using `sudo python`.